# error: 'src/' does not have a commit checked out fatal: adding files failed

Tags: git, github

I am a beginner

I am designing a basic website and I have three folder in `src` folder (`db conn.js, app.js and models`).
But after using git add . I got this

```
error: 'src/' does not have a commit checked out 
fatal: adding files failed
```

I want to add these files to my github repository.

Comment: Share the output of `git status`

Comment: Note that this question has a better subject line than the linked duplicate (so this duplicate should not be deleted).